# Catching exceptions and errors from junit tests without stopping the program?

Tags: java, testing, selenium, junit

I am using junit and selenium to test a web application and I have a test suite that I'm running. Sometimes when a web page fails to load properly in the browser, tests will fail through no fault of the actual application. To remedy this I wanted to catch any first time errors and run tests again to ensure that the problem indeed lies with the application.
I've tried the code below.

```
try{
        ts.runTest(ts.testAt(testNum), a);
    }
    catch (Error er){
        ts.runTest(ts.testAt(testNum),  a);
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        ts.runTest(ts.testAt(testNum),  a);
    }
```

Ive also tried this

```
ts.runTest(ts.testAt(testNum),  a);
if (!a.wasSuccessful()){
            ts.runTest(ts.testAt(testNum), a);
            if (!a.wasSuccessful()){
                fail();
                System.out.println("Test "+testNum+" failed");
            }
        }
```

But in both tests the program stops testing entirely the first time it encounters an error. I need to be able to run these tests multiple times despite failures.

Comment: You can use a JUnit @Rule. See https://gist.github.com/abyx/897229 for inspiration

Answer (score 0):

I beleive the easiest way to handle this issue will be to check if your page has loaded before even start executing tests. I am not sure how your tests navigation works. But for me it's something like this we use

```
public SomePage ClickUpdate()
    {
        Driver.FindElement(By.Id("MyId")).Click();
        //taking page objects in return
        return new SomePage (Driver);
    }
```

And inside the SomePage() object use a unique selector and inside the constructor wait until that to exist and wrap that in try catch

```
try
{
    var wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
    wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.Id("Your Id")));
}
catch (YourException)
{
    Driver.Navigate().Refresh();
    // Or you can perform another click to allow the page to load
    var wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
    wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.Id("Your Id")));
}
```

Mine is C#. Hope this helps